# get sum of quantity in week from Tuesday To Monday

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I'm using SQL SERVER 2005 and have a table which stores challans datewise. It has a field 'Quantity'
I want to have a sum of Quantity for the weeks of the month. But these weeks have to start from Tuesday To Monday (*this is an international standard for Oil Accounting*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use set DATEFIRST to set the first day of the week, and then use datepart.

These SQL Statements should get you what you want.  Assumption is that your table is called  and the date column is

SET DATEFIRST 2;

select datepart(week, :my_date), sum(quantity)
from 
group by datepart(week, :my_date)

Comment: O Hail !!! @Steven Mastandrea .... That was Exactly what i was looking for ... Thank You very much... never thought this forum is so helpful and quick... thanks once again

Comment: is it possible to show the dates in the results pane too? i mean, From what date till what date did it calculate the week...? any possibility?

Comment: Not easily, that I can think of, unfortunately.